# Adding a quantity to elements of a matrix that are higher than a quantity

Tags: matlab

how can I add `8` to the elements of matrix

```
a=[1 7 5 7 2 3 8 2 9 5]
```

that are greater than `3` without using a `for`-loop? The desired result is matrix

```
b=[1 15 13 15 2 3 16 2 17 13]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a logical vector, where each of the elements of `a` that are larger than 3 are 1, and all that are not larger than 3 are 0. This vector can be multiplied by 8, and added to the original `a` vector:

```
b = a + 8 * (a>3);
```

**Breakdown**

Create a logical vector:

```
a>3
ans =
   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1
```

Multiply vector by 8:

```
8 * (a>3)
ans =
   0   8   8   8   0   0   8   0   8   8
```

And add it to `a`:

```
b = a + 8*(a>3)
b =
    1   15   13   15    2    3   16    2   17   13
```